Is there a way to know how long it has taken for a materialized view refresh to complete?
I have created few materialized views for tables over dblink. When the materialized views were first created it took almost 20+ minutes as the data was huge. So, i would like to know, for further refreshes of these materialized views, how long it has taken for the refreshes to complete. I tried search in web, most of the answers are towards getting the last refresh time.

How do you refresh the materialized view? When you run it by PL/SQL procedure, then you can implement a simple timer. If the refresh is done by scheduler job, then have a look at view USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS

The materialized view is created with REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT sysdate + (30/1440) option. Does this come under scheduler based refresh?

The refresh is done by (legacy) job. As far as I know in newer Oracle versions the legacy jobs are migrated to modern scheduler jobs. Thus, view USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS should provide the duration. Otherwise I would suggest to drop the JOB and create SCHEDULER JOB doing the refresh.

SELECT mview_name, last_refresh_date, last_refresh_end_time
FROM user_mviews ;

select last_refresh_date,
       last_refresh_end_time,
        extract ( day from diff ) days,
        extract ( hour from diff ) hours,
        extract ( minute from diff ) minutes,
        extract ( second from diff ) seconds
from (
    SELECT mview_name,
           last_refresh_date,
           last_refresh_end_time,
           numtodsinterval(last_refresh_end_time - last_refresh_date, 'day') as diff
    FROM user_mviews
);




LAST_REFRESH_DATE
LAST_REFRESH_END_TIME
DAYS
HOURS
MINUTES
SECONDS




2024-07-22 13:15:00
2024-07-22 13:15:21
0
0
0
21


2024-07-22 13:15:00
2024-07-22 13:15:27
0
0
0
27


2024-07-22 13:15:00
2024-07-22 13:15:00
0
0
0
0


2024-07-24 20:28:54
2024-07-24 20:28:54
0
0
0
0


2024-07-25 02:42:45
2024-07-25 02:42:49
0
0
0
4


2024-07-22 13:15:00
2024-07-22 13:15:01
0
0
0
1


2024-07-22 13:15:00
2024-07-22 13:29:38
0
0
14
38


2024-07-22 13:15:00
2024-07-22 13:28:27
0
0
13
27


2024-04-08 01:50:53
2024-04-08 01:50:53
0
0
0
0


2024-04-08 01:56:10
2024-04-08 01:56:10
0
0
0
0




Thank you @christianbogiorno. So, last_refresh_date is the start time of the materialized view refresh and last_refresh_end_time is the end time of the materialized view refresh?
